# MVC 3 "does not contain a definition for validationmessagefor"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, html-helper

I have the following code attempting to extend @Html.ValidationMessageFor with my own @Html.MyValidationMessageFor(model => model.myfield) and provide a custom error html

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Hml.BackEnd.Helpers
{
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        string myContent = "<div>" + htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString() + "</div>";
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(myContent);
    }
}
}
```

I get the following compilation message:

'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper < Model > does not contain a definition for ValidationMessageFor and no extension method ValidationMessageFor accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper < TModel > could be found are you missing a using or assembly reference.

I can't understand since System.Web.Mvc is in the project references and in the using.

Comment: you need System.Web.Mvc.Html for ValidationMessageFor

Comment: thank you that worked - i was scratching my head for a while on that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is part of the [System.Web.Mvc.Html](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) namespace.  You need to reference `ValidationExtensions` either explicitly, using the full namespace, or include `System.Web.Mvc.Html` within your `using` directives.